# Simple Sleep() not working in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a project than involves making an image appear and then disappear after a fixed time. I thought that the correct function for that purpose would be `Thread::Sleep()` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
this->pictureTConf->Visible = true;  
Thread::Sleep(5000);
this->pictureTConf->Visible = false;
```

With this code, the picture doesn't appear at any moment. Any thoughts? Thanks.

PD: Using Visual Studio, Windows forms and VC++.

Comment: Sleeping your thread means it does nothing in between those two statements, including updating the window to not draw the picture. Use a timer with a callback instead.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a member variable to true isn't enough because your call to Sleep() prevents the code from running the message loop. Try this instead: (This is just for sample purposes, you shouldn't do this in a "real" application.)

```
this->pictureTConf->Visible = true;  
this->pictureTConf->Refresh();
Thread::Sleep(5000);
this->pictureTConf->Visible = false;
this->pictureTConf->Refresh();
```

Also, as Chuck pointed out, if you use a timer, you shouldn't need the calls to Refresh(). Everything will just work.